# Как выгрузить фотографию из MSSQL средствами php?

Tags: изображения, php, sql-server, img

Я никогда не хранил фотографии в базе данной, только имея и путь к ней.
Тут столкнулся с тем что все изображения хранятся в таблице СУБД MSSQL на уровне SQL, данные преобразуются в IMAGE.

В таблице есть поля:

```
SIZE - float
TOPIC - VARCHAR(60)
DATA - image
FILENAME - varchar(255)
UID - varchar(50)
COMPRESSED - CHAR(1)
COMPRESSED_SIZE - FLOAT
```

SQL запрос я написал, он прост:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSATTACHMENT1 WHERE TOPIC='Пользователь1';
```

Какие дальнейшие мои действия я понять не могу. Прошу помочь разобраться в данной задаче. 
Я пробовал выгружать данные из поля DATA, получается просто огромный непонятный код на странице.

Гуглил, ничего пока не нашел интересного..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто: выполнить команду, отдать файл (на диск сохранять не нужно). Как отдать файл, читайте описание протокола http (какие заголовки должны быть у http-response, чтобы его принимали за файл).

Правда файл может быть очень большим - посмотрите, нет ли в php возможности получать данные из СУБД порциями.

Comment: Посмотрел про http-response, в примерах указаны опеределнные расширения картинок, как с ними быть?
Пример: header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
Будет ли работать такая конструкция: header("Content-Type: image/*");
где * - это какое расширение картинки, определит ли браузер это расширение самостоятельно? В БД нигде расширения не хранятся.

Comment: 1. У вас есть поле `FILENAME - varchar(255)`. Возможно в нём есть расширение файла, по которому можно выставить `Content-Type`

2. В PHP есть возможность определять тип файла по его содержимому. Смотрите функции [`getimagesize()`][1] и [`getimagesizefromstring()`][2]


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php
  [2]: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php

Comment: @mantigatos Как не странно звучало, разработчик в это полу запихал информацию, кому принадлежит файл. с типами разобрался. спасибо